# Finding the intersection between two lengths

Tags: math, intersection

If i have a pen with length 5meters and an area (1d) with length 20 meters, and an optimal area from meter 5 to meter 13 in this area. How do i compute how much of the pen is not covered by the optimal area when putting it at random.
I.e. I have the start location of the pen, the end location of the pen, the length of the pen, the start location of the optimal spot, the end location of the optimal spot.

I though this is some sort of intersection computation. However I'm not sure.

If i place my pen with start location at meter 3, end location of meter 8, i have 2 meters of the pen not covered by the optimal area, and thus the result is 2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about straight mathematics rather than programming. [mathematics.se] would be a better fit, but make sure that you first read their posting guidelines.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It does look like a math problem--please explain how it is a problem in practical computer programming. Also, your description of the problem is confusing. Could you use the original wording, or show us an image of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand this correctly.

We have some line of length 20 metres of which the section from a 5-meter mark to a 13-meter mark is 'optimal'. And we want to know how much of a 5-metre long pen 'sticks out' of this section, if the pen is positioned randomly?

I assume the pen can only be positioned on this line with a length of 20 metres and that it is positioned randomly (i.e. with a uniform distribution). We can divide the possible positionings into three cases:

1. The pen is entirely **outside** the optimal area. This happens if the pen is positioned at exactly the first 5 metres or after the first 13 metres. The first case has a probability of 0 and the last of 2/15, since the position of the left-hand end of the pen can span 2 metres out of 15 possible, starting from the 13-meter mark and ending at the 15-meter mark.
2. The pen is entirely **inside** the optimal area. This happens when the position of the pen's left endpoint is positioned from the 5 meter to the 8 meter mark i.e. with a probability of 3/15.
3. The pen stick out of one of the ends. This happens with the remaining probability of 10/15. It will only stick out of one end, and since the positioning is random, half of the pen is sticking out on average (2.5 m).

The average length of pen outside the optimal area is then 2/15 * 5m + 3/15 * 0m + 10/15 * 2.5m = 35 m / 15 = 2.33.. m

If the pen **can** actually 'stick out' of the 20-metre line, then the probabilities can be adjusted to account for this.

Also, this is my first answer, so hi everyone.